# Recruiter for potential future employer asked to remove profile at job portal. Is this a valid request?

Tags: job-search, job-offer, recruitment, job-change

I have recieved a job offer from a company 2 weeks back. I have resigned from my current organisation, notified the last date, provided all required documents for joining, and also recieved a date of joining from the new company.

I was contacted about this position by a recruiter who was probably hired by the company to reach out to potential candidates.

Now this recruiter has called me and asked me about my interest to join the new place because she saw my status on a job portal as "active". When I replied that I am definitely interested in the new job - she even asked me if I can delete my profile from the job portal, which I refused stating that I cannot probably pull down all my career related info because I have an offer and she some what came to an agreement (didn't sound too happy about it).

Now my question is :

1. Is asking me to pull down my profile a valid request?
2. Is she likely getting pushed by the company HR to do this?
3. Can my negative response to this request have any impact on the offer?

Let me know please.

P.S: The offer is pretty decent and a good percentage above my current salary.
I am reluctant to pull down my career profiles because I am not feeling very secure in the present covid situation and want to have options open.

Comment: Is the company also going to remove the job from its hiring page as soon as someone sends them a resume?

Comment: Yes. Exactly my point.

Comment: @Monalisa - Sounds like this recruiter wasn't involved in your recruitment to the company, is asking you to make this change to your profile, so it benefits them.  I would simply ignore the request.  I was once recruited (called) by two different recruiters, one before I interviewed at the company, and another after I had done so.  Since the company was absolutely horrible, I told both recruiters, exactly what I thought of the company.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is reasonable for them to ask you to delete it. It would be more reasonable to request that you set it to Private/Not Actively Looking/Etc. That being said, you don't have that job yet. I do not believe you need do anything until you are actually employed and on the payroll.

And while your response could have an impact on the offer, it also presents you with additional information about this opportunity. If it is your future employer's HR pushing for this, that seems like quite a bit of controlling behavior right out of the gate. That may change your decision to take the offered job.

Comment: If a company requested I change the status of a profile, which indicate I was or was not looking for a job, I would ignore that request.  **It isn't a reasonable request.**  Which makes my believe the company has nothing to do with the request.

Answer (score 1):

> Is asking me to pull down my profile a valid request?

People can ask anything they want and you are under no obligation to comply.

> Is she likely getting pushed by the company HR to do this?

Doesn't matter so what's the point in guessing?

> Can my negative response to this request have any impact on the offer?

Absolutely. Whether it's minor or a major one depends directly on how much the recruiter cares.